# read only mongos access without enabling authentication

Tags: mongodb

We have a recently sharded mongodb cluster. Before sharding, for read-only access, all users used to connect to one of the secondaries. We need a similar read-only access now when users connect to 'mongos' (after sharding). One option is to enable authentication and add user user roles. But that will mean changing java code on some app module which connect to the mongos using the java connector.

Is there a way to obtain read-only access without enabling authentication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only create read-only roles by enabling authentication. If you do not want to enable authentication, your human users have to specify their read preference explicitly when connecting. As they may forget this, I would advise you enable authentication. It will allow you more granular access in the future and will allow users to continue the data when the secondary servers are down (e.g. maintenance).

Comment: Thank you. We already have the code you shown in the software modules. What we need currently is read-only access to (human) users who have to access the same mongodb cluster using mongos shell.

Comment: I change my answer. I am afraid your options are limited